# how to get object identifier of a row in oracle 10g?

Tags: oracle, ordbms

I am new to ORDBMS using Oracle 10g express edition and I have to get the object identifier of each row in an object table. I am using the below example.

```
CREATE TYPE person AS OBJECT(
name VARCHAR2(20)
);

CREATE TABLE person_table OF person;
INSERT INTO person_table VALUES ( person('Test') );
```

The Type person and Table person_table are successfully created. The row is inserted and I can retrieve the row using

```
SELECT * from person_table;
```

But executing

```
SELECT REF(p) FROM person_table p;
```

gives the following error:

`ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got REF SYS.PERSON`

How to get the object identifier of each row of the table? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do You mean `rowid` ? => http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns008.htm  ?

Answer (score 0):

I see that the error is refering to SYS.PERSON. Did you create the object and table as the SYS user? If so, try creating it as "normal" user, not the SYS user.

Comment: I tried doing it from a normal account as well but it gives the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get the *OBJECT_ID* pseudocolumn like this getting each object attribute as separate column:

```
SELECT OBJECT_ID, p.* FROM person_table p;
```

or treat entire row as object with *VALUE()* function:

```
SELECT OBJECT_ID, VALUE(p) FROM person_table p;
```

*ROWID* is different value assigned to each row in database tables, not only to object tables. Your question was about OBJECT_ID, but You can show it as well:

```
SELECT OBJECT_ID, ROWID, p.* FROM person_table p;
SELECT OBJECT_ID, ROWID, VALUE(p) FROM person_table p;
```

See: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/pseudocolumns004.htm